# Android studio doesn't display it's interface correctly

Tags: android, user-interface, intellij-idea, ide

I mean ide user interface, not android UI designer or something android specific. 
Screen:
http://postimg.org/image/7fg6sdcnl/

Comment: Not a programming problem. Probably an issue with OP's graphics card/OS. Might have better luck in http://superuser.com/ if OP includes OS/machine type/any graphics info.

Comment: Sorry for unrelated question, and thanks for link.

Answer (score 0):

**Restart** your computer and/or **update** your video card driver.

By the way it's not a programming question, so there is no programming solution.